# Regression of Higher order

Tags: r, regression, lm

I want to fit a model $Y = X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_1 + X_2 + X_1\cdot X_2$

How to build this in R

```
glm(Y ~ poly(X1,2) * poly(X2,2)
```

how to generalise it to higher order ?
eg. $Y = X_1^3 + X_2^3 + X_1\cdot X_2^2 + X_1^2 \cdot X_2 + X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_1 + X_2 + X_1\cdot X_2$

Comment: I like to fit a higher order model by regression with more than 1 parameters.

Comment: consider changing the second argument to `poly` from 2 to 3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `glm` with the following formula:

```
glm(Y ~ poly(X1, 2) + poly(X2, 2) + X1:X2)
```

The function `poly` creates polynomials. In your example, `poly(X1, 2)` results in $X_1$ and $X_1^2$. Note that `poly` creates [orthogonal polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials). If you want raw polynomials, you have to use the argument `raw = TRUE`.

The term `X1:X2` is the interaction between $X_1$ and $X_2$, i.e., $X_1 \cdot X_2$.

Furthermore, your formula doesn't contain an intercept. I suppose this was not intended. However, you you really want to create a model without an intercept in R, you have to change the command to `glm(Y ~ 0 + poly(X1, 2) + poly(X2, 2) + X1:X2)`.

Note that unless you specify a `family` in `glm`, the function will fit a linear model.

---

The formula you proposed (`Y ~ poly(X1,2) * poly(X2,2)`) creates all the terms of the formula above and additional terms, namely all interactions between the polynomials of first and second order of $X_1$, and $X_2$, i.e., $X_1 \cdot X_2^2$, $X_1^2 \cdot X_2$, and $X_1^2 \cdot X_2^2$.

Comment: So , is there a way to genralize this for more variables ? say X1 to X5 ? what ever order it be ?